# Возникает WebException при загрузке файла

Tags: c#, winforms, сервер, http-status-code-404

Программа работает некоторое время стабильно, ошибка возникает лишь через некоторое время, ссылки на файлы все правильные.Скажите, пожалуйста, из-за чего возникает следующая ошибка и как её можно решить.

```
private string[] DownloadFileFromServer(string from, string to)
{
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadFile(from , to);
        }
        string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(to);
        File.Delete(to);
        return file;              
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]